# Environment Config Files with Create React App

Tags: reactjs, configuration, create-react-app

I'm building a React / TypeScript app via Create React App and am looking to include environment specific configuration in a type safe way. Caveat, I really would rather not `eject` the app.

Ideally, I would like to have a set of files `local.ts`, `dev.ts`, `prod.ts`, etc. Each file would export an object of the same type, something like the following:

```
interface EnvConfig {
  key: string
  // ...
}

export const config: EnvConfig = {
  key: 'value',
  // ...
}
```

Then, in my app I'd like to import the appropriate config based on the environment. Something along the lines of:

```
// This is bundling BOTH prod and local configs and running logic client side!
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  return require('./prod')
} else {
  return require('./local')
}
```

I have tried this and it *sort of* works, but if you look at the bundle react-scripts is including ALL of the config objects and running the logic on the client to determine which one to serve up. I don't want to ship ALL of my configs, only the appropriate config for the build.

Is there a way to do this without ejecting the app?

Comment: Hey Josh, did you end up solving this, and if so, how?